# Create photo album with Facebook SDK on iOS using Open Graph

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I need to create a new photo album using the Facebook SDK on iOS. My code was working, but has recently started returning errors like this:

```
{
    "com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey" = "<FBSession: 0x7290850, state: FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended, loginHandler: 0x7290c40, appID: 380841565285975, urlSchemeSuffix: , tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: 0x8a933e0>, expirationDate: 4001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000, refreshDate: 2013-10-14 03:16:01 +0000, attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(\n    \"create_note\",\n    \"basic_info\",\n    \"share_item\",\n    \"status_update\",\n    \"publish_actions\",\n    \"video_upload\",\n    email,\n    \"photo_upload\",\n    installed,\n    \"publish_stream\",\n    \"user_birthday\",\n    \"user_location\"\n)>";
    "com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode" = 500;
    "com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey" =     {
        body =         {
            error =             {
                code = 2;
                message = "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.";
                type = OAuthException;
            };
        };
        code = 500;
    };
}
```

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/errors/ , and error with code 2 is: "Server-side problem; app should retry after waiting, up to some app-defined threshold".

This has been failing for at least a few days though, and I can't seem to find anyone else having similar trouble, so I'm assuming the problem is my own.

Any ideas what could be the cause? Relevant code is below. The `createFacebookAlbum` method is the one that is failing.

```
- (void)shareToFacebook {
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
    NSLog(@"SESSION IS OPEN");

    [self createFacebookAlbum];
} else {
    NSLog(@"SESSION IS NOT OPEN");
    NSArray* permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"email"];
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
        [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];

        if (error) {
            /* handle failure */
            NSLog(@"error:%@, %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
            UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"There was a problem with your Facebook permissions." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];
        }
        else if (state == FBSessionStateClosed || state == FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed ) {
            [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
        }
        else if (state == FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended || state == FBSessionStateOpen) {
            if(!self.presentedFacebookSheet) {
                [self performSelector:@selector(reauthorizeAndContinuePostToFacebook) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
                self.presentedFacebookSheet = YES;
            }
        }
        }];
    }
}

- (void)reauthorizeAndContinuePostToFacebook {
    NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_actions", nil];

    [[FBSession activeSession] requestNewPublishPermissions:permissions defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
        [self shareToFacebook];
    }];
}

- (void)createFacebookAlbum {
    NSMutableDictionary* parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [parameters setObject:@"Test name" forKey:@"name"];
    [parameters setObject:@"Test message" forKey:@"message"];

    FBRequest* request = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me/albums" parameters:parameters HTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSLog(@"creating facebook album");
    FBRequestConnection *connection = [[FBRequestConnection alloc] init];
    [connection addRequest:request
         completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {
                 NSString* albumId = [result objectForKey:@"id"];
                 NSLog(@"OK %@", albumId);
             }
             else {
                 NSLog(@"Error: %@",error.userInfo);
             }
         }];
    [connection start];
}

- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState) state error:(NSError *)error {
    switch (state) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen:
        {
            [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
             ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
               NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user,
               NSError *error) {
                 if (error) {
                     //error
                 }
                 else {
                     NSLog(@"User session found");
                 }
             }];
        }
            break;
        case FBSessionStateClosed:
        case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
            [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you change anything in your info.plist before this started? Have you tried removing the token (logging out) and trying again?

Comment: No, this is an existing app on the store which I haven't touched in a couple months. I've tried deleting and fresh installing the app as well, but no luck. I've even tried with a different bundle ID and app ID...no luck with that, either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem as you. 
One month ago, I could create albums without `user_photos`.

But now not anymore.

I add the permission: `user_photos` and it works again.

See also that article on facebook about change to permissions
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/

Comment: Thanks, this solved it. I had to be sure to logout the user first so that the permissions would be re-requested, but after that it worked fine. The documentation link above still mentions that to create an album, you should only need publish_actions. But, user_photos is definitely required! Enjoy your bounty, thanks for helping.